# OpError: The system cannot find the file specified. ; No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, model, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:SavedModel saved prior to TF 2.5 detected when loading Keras model.
 Please ensure that you are saving the model with model.save() or tf.keras.models.save_model(), *NOT* tf.saved_model.save().
 To confirm, there should be a file named "keras_metadata.pb" in the SavedModel directory.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OpError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11864/674996100.py in <module>
----> 1 yolo_model = load_model("model_data/", compile=False)

~\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py in error_translator(e)
     47     raise errors_impl.InternalError(None, None, error_message)
     48   else:
---> 49     raise errors_impl.OpError(None, None, error_message, errors_impl.UNKNOWN)
     50 
     51 

OpError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: model_data/variables\variables.data-00000-of-00001 : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
```

I just downloaded new tensorflow module and tried to run my old DL model , I got an error like the above , this error was not there in previous versions of tensorflow version,

what is remedy for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on Windows. Windows uses backslashes `\` in file paths. Your code should work after removing the forward slash in `load_model`.